# Yii: If variable is equal 0 icon as link, else icon open alert

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I have CButtonColumn in CGridView:

```
array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                        'template'=>'{document}',
                        'buttons'=>array(
                            'document'=>array(
                                'imageUrl'=>'icon.gif',
                                'url' => '($data->status=="1") ? Yii::app()->createUrl("site/getDocument") : "" ',
                                'click' => 'js:function() { alert("There isn't file");}'
                            ),
                        ),
        ),
```

But I want open will be opening alert only when $data->status=="1", but I can't insert php code in 'click'. So There is any possibility to do this?

Comment: did you try to use $data->status with CJavascript::encode($data->status) ? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJavaScript

Comment: In 'click' isn't possible to use PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn:

```
'buttonID' => array(
    'label'=>'...',     // text label of the button
    'url'=>'...',       // a PHP expression for generating the URL of the button
    'imageUrl'=>'...',  // image URL of the button. If not set or false, a text link is used
    'options'=>array(...), // HTML options for the button tag
    'click'=>'...',     // a JS function to be invoked when the button is clicked
    'visible'=>'...',   // a PHP expression for determining whether the button is visible
)
```

"In the PHP expression for the 'url' option and/or 'visible' option, the variable $row refers to the current row number (zero-based), and $data refers to the data model for the row. A PHP expression can be any PHP code that has a value." You can access elements on DOM to get the values you want.

You can try this:

```
array(
      'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{document}',
            'buttons'=>array(
                        'document'=>array(
                        'imageUrl'=>'icon.gif',
                        'url' => '($data->status=="1") ? Yii::app()->createUrl("site/getDocument") : "" ',

                'click' => 'function() { if($(this).attr("href") !== "") alert("There isn't file");}',
                            ),
                        ),
        ),
```